# How to add serial number in shell

Tags: linux, shell, printf

I would like to add serial numbers to the following print statement.

```
for i in 1 5 20 50 100 200 500 1000;do
#I have here some computations for each i, finally mean_${i}=xyz
#for example
mean_1=10.42
mean_5=12.43
mean_20=25.34
mean_50=59.34
mean_100=150.32
mean_200=378.43
mean_500=697.45
mean_1000=1233.54
printf "%5s %10s %10s\n" sl.No. "$i" "mean_${i}" >> ofile.txt
done
```

I can't able to add the serial numbers.

Desired output

```
ofile.txt
1  1    10.42
2  5    12.43
3  20   25.34
4  50   59.34
5  100  150.32
6  200  378.43
7  500  697.45
8  1000 1233.54
```

Comment: `NR` has meaning in awk, not bash. (They're two completely different languages).

Comment: I see. Would you please suggest how to do it in my print statement. Thank you very much

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't have expected `"$mean_{i}"` to work as-expected either. See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for a full discussion of indirect variable usage, including lookups.

Comment: Oh!! there was a typo error

Comment: `"$mean_${i}"` concatenates two values -- that of the variable named `$mean_`, and that of the variable `$i`; even if `i=1`, it doesn't dereference `$mean_1`.

Comment: Anyway, I was facing the problem in the print statement while adding a serial number. Others were okay in my script. Now it works great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kay: You could very well remove the `NR` from your `printf`, doesn't make sense without `awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean "line numbers" -- `NR` refers to the current line number in `awk`; however, while awk is frequently used from shell, it is its own independent programming language with its own syntax.

Maintaining an explicit counter is the typical practice, as in the case of `ln` below:

```
mean_1=10.42
mean_5=12.43
mean_20=25.34
mean_50=59.34
mean_100=150.32
mean_200=378.43
mean_500=697.45
mean_1000=1233.54

ln=0
for i in 1 5 20 50 100 200 500 100; do
  meanvar=mean_$i
  printf '%5s %10s %10s\n' "$((++ln))" "$i" "${!meanvar}"
done
```